# Infinite retries/loop with DefaultErrorHandler with ConsumerRecordRecoverer and BackOff

Tags: spring-kafka

i I have a KafkaListener that throw a NPE.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = CASE6_TOPIC, groupId = "demo-case-6", clientIdPrefix = "case6", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
private void consume(DemandeAvro payload, @Header(RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) Integer partitionId, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offset) {
    log.info(String.format("Partition %s Offset %s Payload : %s", partitionId, offset, payload));
    throw new NullPointerException("other than serde");
}
```

My configuration look like :

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate());
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(recoverer(kafkaTemplate()),new FixedBackOff(2000L, 4)));
    return factory;
}
```

And the recovrer to publish on DLT

```
@Bean
public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer(KafkaTemplate<?, ?> bytesTemplate) {
    return new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(bytesTemplate);
}
```

I'm not sure if it'is a bad use or a bug , but when i drop the recoverer, the consumer will stop after 4 attempts like i'm asking on the FixedBackOff policy , otherwise it will retries forever ...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are saying; with no recoverer the failed message will be logged after 4 retries; with the DLPR, it will be published to the DLT. If the publishing fails, the record will be delivered again as if retries were not exhausted.

If you are seeing this behavior, the DLT publishing must be failing for some reason.

Comment: Thank you Garry for your response 
I'm trying to deal with two types of exceptions 
First type are "poisin pill" handled with ErrorHandlingDeserializer and then published to DLT. ( work fine and published to a DLT)
And other Exceptions (runtime, domaine, functionnel..) that can be trigged inside my Listener and may just be retried 4 times or by default 9 times before skipping it
What's the best practice to handled properly the second case, should i use a custom CommonErrorHandler ?

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh (scroll to the end of that section). You can set a backoff function to select a different `BackOff` to use for specific exceptions.